# Serializing associations as an array of IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to serialize a model's association as an array of ID's (int) of the associated models.
I'm currently using :include option in serializable_hash as such:

```
:include => {:associated => {:only => [:id]}
```

wich output json like:

```
{"id":13, ...,"associated":[{"id":15,"associated":[]},{"id":14,"associated":[]}]}
```

Don't know why the object corresponding to associated have an "associated" key; but that's not very important; what I want is to get an output like:

```
{"id":13, "associated":[15,14]}
```

What should I do to get this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the `associated` model ids, you could try creating a method in the parent model like:

```
class ParentModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def associated_ids
    associated.pluck(:id)
  end
end
```

Then in the `serializable_hash` or `to_json` method, I would do this:

```
parent_model_instance.includes(:associated).serializable_hash(methods: [:associated_ids])
```

Which should produce this:

```
{ "id": 13, "associated_ids": [15,14] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do this with this in your serializer:

```
 class SomeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   embed :ids
   has_many :associateds
 end
```